# how you know which item is an image or button

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am having a problem in pass image props in ReactJs

This is my code for that:`component/Table/index`. This component use for 2 tables (Order and Product) so I create to like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {Table, Image} from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../Table/index.css';
import Button from '../Button/index';

const TableItem = ({datas, columns}) => {
  return(
    <Table striped bordered hover>
      <thead>
        <tr> 
          {columns.map(name => <th>{name}</th>)}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr> 
          {datas.map(data => 
          <td>{data}</td>
          )}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}

export default TableItem;
```

and I have to import data for that column like this from `app.js`

```
 <TableItem columns={["No.", "Image", "Name", "Category", "Price", "Action"]} 
 datas={["1", "https://place-hold.it/100x150", "MIlk tea", "Milk tea", "100000", "button"]}
 />
```

As you see above I have imported the data for all column, but has a problem that, in column Image, I do not have `<Image>` tag for that so that can not be displayed for me the data of image link, **and also I have 1 column is Action**, in this column will have **two buttons**, **Edit and delete for each row of each product**
And if I have many **data**, how can I retrieve it in `app.js` file

I do not have any idea to solve that, can anyone help me please, this is so hard for me because I very new on ReactJs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is *how* you know which item is an image or button.

If you know its always the one called "Image", you can search for it in the columns, get the index and use that in the loop:

```
const TableItem = ({datas, columns}) => {

  const imageColumnIndex = columns.indexOf('Image');
  const actionColumnIndex = columns.indexOf('Action');

  return(
    <Table striped bordered hover>
      <thead>
        <tr> 
          {columns.map(name => <th>{name}</th>)}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr> 
          {datas.map((data, index) => 
          <td>
            {index === actionColumnIndex ? (
              <React.Fragment>
                {data.includes('edit') && <button type="button">Edit</button>}
                {data.includes('delete') && <button type="button">Delete</button>}
              </React.Fragment>
            ) : (
              index === imageColumnIndex ? <img src={data}/> : data
            )}
          </td>
          )}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}
```

Then in your `app.js`, using `edit` and `delete` as button examples:

```
const columns = ["No.", "Image", "Name", "Category", "Price", "Action"];
const datas = ["1", "https://place-hold.it/100x150", "MIlk tea", "Milk tea", "100000", "edit,delete"];

return <TableItem columns={columns} datas={datas}/>
```

Note: if you havent seen the `<condition? ? <true> : <false>` yet, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: @Erme Koc But it's displayed for me both text and image, how can I show just image not text. Can you help me with this problem, I'm so confused about this case

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you see? Or you can recreate it in https://codesandbox.io so we can take a look

Comment: Sorry, that my fault, I want to ask like this, If I have two button on "Action" column, how can I add it, example data: <TableItem columns={["No.", "Image", "Name", "Category", "Price", "Action"]} 
          datas={["1", "https://place-hold.it/100x150", "MIlk tea", "Milk tea", "100000", <Button variant="success">Edit</Button>]}
        />. my button is a component, I have import from another folder `src/components/Button/index`

Comment: Updated the answer to include the buttons. You can add multiple buttons like this, defined in the `app.js` and configure them individually. Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it should work :)